# Express router param - chaining with URL

Tags: node.js, express

I have a full CRUD API defined in Express, and I'd like to remove the duplication of base and use the snazzy `route` function, but I fear it's not possible.

Current:

```
var router = express.Router();
var base = '/api/foo/bar/';
router.get(base, this.list);
router.get(base + ':id', this.read);
router.post(base, this.create);
router.put(base + :id', this.update);
router.del(base + :id', this.del);
```

Desired:

```
var router = express.Router();
router.route('/api/foo/bar')
  .get(this.list)
  .get(':id', this.read)
  .post(this.create)
  .put(':id', this.update)
  .del(':id', this.del)
```

The problem is that the verb functions (get, post, put, del) do not accept a string as their first parameter.

Is there a similar way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Important:** Using this technique will work, but we aware that as of Express 4.3.2, all subroutes defined on the nested router will not have access to `req.params` defined outside of it, nor param middleware.  It's completely quarantined.  This, however, is subject to change in a later 4X version.  See https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/2151 for more (up to date) info.

---

How about this instead:

```
// api.js
var router = express.Router();
router
  .route('/')
    .get(this.list)
    .post(this.create);
router
  .route('/:id')
    .get(this.read)
    .put(this.update)
    .del(this.del);
module.exports = router;

// app.js / main.js
app.use('/api/foo/bar', require('./api'));
```

or if you want to chain all of them at once:

```
// api.js
var router = express.Router();
router
  .get('/', this.list)
  .get('/:id', this.read)
  .post('/', this.create)
  .put('/:id', this.update)
  .del('/:id', this.del);
module.exports = router;

// app.js / main.js
app.use('/api/foo/bar', require('./api'));
```

Comment: Do you know if you can nest express routers, off-hand?  Because this looks good, the only issue is that the thing app.using this bit of code will actually be another router.  Does that work?

Comment: Well I answered my own question with some local testing.  Seems this will indeed work.  Unfortunately, however, routers do not seem to allow calls like `router.get(this.list)`.  You must provide it a path: `router.get('/', this.list)`.  I'll accept your answer if you could change it to reflect this, just in case people will be misled.

Comment: Nested routers should work fine as a router is basically a middleware function itself.